# Existence of classical solution for Poisson's equation

Tags: poissons-equation

I read a bit through uniqueness of the solution to Poisson's equation with boundary data and also existence/uniqueness of the variational formulation. But under what conditions can one guarantee the existence of a  classical solution for Poissons equation $$-\Delta u =f$$
with given boundary data, say dirichlet, $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I am also happy with reference to literature where the existence of a classical solution is being discussed

Comment: Pages 365-368 of "Methods of Mathematical Physics" (Vol 1) by Courant and Hilbert might be helpful for the case  n=2,3